Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata' while creating an app using React Native
While running my code I'm getting the following error
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

   > Failed to transform react-android-0.73.6-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.73.6) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.

      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\jkman\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.facebook.react\react-android\0.73.6\d3e299ab584daa7577b1849eef7ab2d84001dab4\react-android-0.73.6-debug.aar.

         > Java heap space
   > Failed to transform hermes-android-0.73.6-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:hermes-android:0.73.6) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.

      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\jkman\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.facebook.react\hermes-android\0.73.6\6880af8edd63dc1b331d2f42198856c9a822cdb0\hermes-android-0.73.6-debug.aar.

         > Java heap space

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 15s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'. > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'. > Failed to transform react-android-0.73.6-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.73.6) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}. > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\jkman\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.facebook.react\react-android\0.73.6\d3e299ab584daa7577b1849eef7ab2d84001dab4\react-android-0.73.6-debug.aar. > Java heap space > Failed to transform hermes-android-0.73.6-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:hermes-android:0.73.6) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}. > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\jkman\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.facebook.react\hermes-android\0.73.6\6880af8edd63dc1b331d2f42198856c9a822cdb0\hermes-android-0.73.6-debug.aar. > Java heap space * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 15s.

I tried to clear the cache in Port 8081 and also invalidating cache in Android Studio and wiping data from the AVD. Still this error persists.

Update the AVD Configuration. Increase the RAM and VM heap.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
